# Error when running R file from command line

Tags: r, command-line

I have an R file which imports a file, does some data manipulation, and performs a logistic regression model, and then saves those results to a txt file. However, when I run the file from the command line, I get the following error message and don't know what's going on.

```
anonymous@anonymous-Latitude-E6520:~/Downloads$ R --no-save < Auto_Model.r > out.txt
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
Error in if (x == "\\N") NA else if (x > 1 & x < 6999) "1:6999" else if (x >  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Calls: bin.value -> do.call -> mapply -> .Call -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
anonymous@anonymous-Latitude-E6520:~/Downloads$ R --no-save < Auto_Model.r
```

The R script which results in the error is below =

```
> ## IMPORT DATA:
> #setwd("~/Desktop")
> library(foreign)
> dat = read.csv("dat.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> 
> ## zipcode = 
> dat$zipcode = as.character(dat$zipcode)
> 
> bin.value = Vectorize(function(x) {
+   if (x == "\\N") NA
+   else if (x > 1 & x < 6999) "1:6999"
+   else if (x > 7000 & x < 9999) "7000:9999"
+   else if (x > 10000 & x < 14849) "10000:14849"
+   else if (x > 14850 & x < 19699) "14850:19699"
+   else if (x > 19700 & x < 29999) "19700:29999"
+   else if (x > 30000 & x < 31999) "30000:31999"
+   else if (x > 32000 & x < 34999) "32000:34999"
+   else if (x > 35000 & x < 42999) "35000:42999"
+   else if (x > 43000 & x < 49999) "43000:49999"
+   else if (x > 50000 & x < 59999) "50000:59999"
+   else if (x > 60000 & x < 69999) "60000:69999"
+   else if (x > 70000 & x < 79999) "70000:79999"
+   else if (x > 80000 & x < 89999) "80000:89999"
+   else if (x > 90000 & x < 96999) "90000:96999"
+   else if (x > 97000 & x < 99820) "97000:99820"
+   else NA 
+ })
> 
> dat$zipcode2 = as.character(bin.value(as.integer(dat$zipcode)))
Error in if (x == "\\N") NA else if (x > 1 & x < 6999) "1:6999" else if (x >  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Calls: bin.value -> do.call -> mapply -> .Call -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

I assume some is wrong in how I am trying to manipulate the mode of the zipcode variable but nothing I've tried seems to fix the issue.

```
> str(dat$zipcode)
 int [1:12635] 76148 33825 61832 11368 98290 92078 44104 62052 55106 20861 ...
>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that what you're trying to do is already done by function `cut`:

```
bin.value <- function(x){
    cut(as.integer(x),
        breaks= c(1,6999,9999,14849,19699,29999,31999,34999,42999,49999,59999,69999,79999,89999,96999,99820),
        labels= c("1:6999", "7000:9999", "10000:14849", "14850:19699", "19700:29999", "30000:31999", "32000:34999", "35000:42999", "43000:49999", "50000:59999", "60000:69999", "70000:79999", "80000:89999", "90000:96999", "97000:99820"))
    }
```

Otherwise your specific problem is caused by `as.integer`:

```
a <- c("\\N",sample(seq(0,100000,by=1),10))
a
[1] "\\N"   "38987" "50403" "75683" "66706" "27924" "17216" "77539" "80658" "2335"  "53010"
as.integer(a)
[1]    NA 38987 50403 75683 66706 27924 17216 77539 80658  2335 53010
```

`\\N` is therefore traited straight away as `NA` which your loop only handle at the end, meanwhile all `if`statements try to compare a missing value with some elements.

```
as.integer(a)[1]=="\\N"
[1] NA # Instead of TRUE or FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a much more elegant way to bucket the variables.